# Macro with some dot field insde it

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a code from ex colleague. he declared some sort of macro like this :

```
#define work_dir "/usr/io/track"
#define macro_test(a1,a2,a3,a4)\
{\
    .name=a1,\
    .family=a2,\
    .idnum=a3,\
    .badlog=a4,\
    }
```

and later on he called this macro like:

```
macro_test(test "John","macdonald",14,"no");
```

I know this might not enough detail, however I am just wondering about declaring this sort of macro. it seems to initialize structure but it is not. much appreciated if you can help me.

Comment: This macro is designed to initialize array of structure and it works now. So it is call in declaring another structure which

Comment: This macro is designed to initialize array of structure and it works now. So it is called inside  declaring another structure which has all those field. so the problem is solved